# unsplit list, merge factors

Tags: r, merge, split, interaction, r-factor

I have the following data frame in R:

```
  c1 c2  
1 10  a  
2 20  a  
3 30  b  
4 40  b
```

I then `split` it as follows: `z = lapply(split(test$c1, test$c2), function(x) {cut(x,2)})`
.  `z` is then:

```
$a  
[1] (9.99,15] (15,20]  
Levels: (9.99,15] (15,20]

$b  
[1] (30,35] (35,40]
Levels: (30,35] (35,40]
```

I would like to then merge the factors back by unsplitting the list `unsplit(z, test$c2)`. This generates a warning:

```
[1] (9.99,15] (15,20]   <NA>      <NA>     
Levels: (9.99,15] (15,20]
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 1:2) :
  invalid factor level, NAs generated
```

I would like to take a union of all the factor levels and then unsplit so that this error does not happen:

```
z$a = factor(z$a, levels=c(levels(z$a), levels(z$b)))
unsplit(z, test$c2)
[1] (9.99,15] (15,20]   (30,35]   (35,40]  
Levels: (9.99,15] (15,20] (30,35] (35,40]
```

In my real data frame I have a very big list so I need to iterate over all the list elements (not just two).  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question properly, I think you are making this a bit more complicated than needed. Here's one solution using `plyr`. We will group by the `c2` variable:

```
require(plyr)
ddply(test, "c2", transform, newvar = cut(c1, 2))
```

which returns:

```
  c1 c2    newvar
1 10  a (9.99,15]
2 20  a   (15,20]
3 30  b   (30,35]
4 40  b   (35,40]
```

and has a structure of:

```
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ c1    : num  10 20 30 40
 $ c2    : Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 1 2 2
 $ newvar: Factor w/ 4 levels "(9.99,15]","(15,20]",..: 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i was looking to do.  Thank you so much for your help! -Alex

Answer (score 4):

Can you not just `unlist()` `z` instead?

```
> unlist(z)
       a1        a2        b1        b2 
(9.99,15]   (15,20]   (30,35]   (35,40] 
Levels: (9.99,15] (15,20] (30,35] (35,40]
```

or without the names on the resulting factor:

```
> unlist(z, use.names=FALSE)
[1] (9.99,15] (15,20]   (30,35]   (35,40]  
Levels: (9.99,15] (15,20] (30,35] (35,40]
```

You can merge everything together into a simple one-liner that needs no add-on packages:

```
> (test2 <- within(test, newvar <- unlist(lapply(split(c1, c2), cut, 2))))
  c1 c2    newvar
1 10  a (9.99,15]
2 20  a   (15,20]
3 30  b   (30,35]
4 40  b   (35,40]
```

Comment: I think the answer below made my code very simple.  Yours works great as well though but i would just have to add it to the data frame.  Thanks for your help! -Alex

Comment: @Alex It wasn't clear you want to stick this back into the original data. I've update my answer to simplify the whole process immensely - 1 line of code does everything you want without extra packages etc.

Comment: I have a minor preference for `(test2 <- transform(test, newvar = unlist(lapply(split(c1, c2), cut, 2))))` [but yours is a few characters shorter]

Comment: I have a question for you guys: I would like to aggregate these factors so that two buckets I split things into using cut get treated the same.  Currently, cut produces two different intervals for each date.  I would like it to produce two "buckets" for each date that are treated the same no matter what date it is.  What is a good way to do this? I tried instead of using cut using: `function(x) {z <- cut(x,2); levels(z)<-c("bucket1", "bucket2")}` but that doesn't seem to work.  Thanks!

Comment: it looks like labels in the cut function would allow me to do this.